# populate immutable sequence with iterator

Tags: scala, iterator, immutability

I'm interoperating with some Java code that uses iterator-like functionality, and presumes you will continue to test it's `.next` for null values.  I want to put it into immutable Scala data structures to reason about it with functional programming.

Right now, I'm filling mutable data structures and then converting them to immutable data structures.  I know there's a more functional way to do this.

**How can I refactor the code below to populate the immutable data structures without using intermediate mutable collections?**

Thanks

```
{
 val sentences = MutableList[Seq[Token]]()
 while(this.next() != null){
   val sentence = MutableList[Token]()
   var token = this.next()
   while(token.next != null){
     sentence += token
     token = token.next
   }
   sentences += sentence.to[Seq]
 }
 sentences.to[Seq]
}
```

Comment: [Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator) has a `toList` and  a `toSeq` method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just directly convert the Java iterator to Scala iterator and `takeWhile(_ != null)`?

Comment: It's not a scala or java iterator.  They are custom java classes that behave like iterators, except without `.hasNext` -- you're expected to check `.next` for `null` values.

Comment: @WalrustheCat Oh well, if it's not an iterator per se, just something that kind of looks like it, then I guess your solution should work. You can create your own Scala iterator with your current implementation as its body, which should make it easier to use from Scala side...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek  Thanks -- can't visualize that. Care to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @WalrustheCat Ben Reich's answer more or less covers all the bases, including creating your own iterator, so I guess you can ask him to elaborate a bit further. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use the `Iterator.iterate` method in order to simulate a real iterator, and then use standard collection methods like `takeWhile` and `toSeq`.  I'm not totally clear on the type of `this` and `next`, but something along these lines might work:

```
Iterator.iterate(this){ _.next }.takeWhile{ _ != null }.map { sentence =>
    Iterator.iterate(sentence.next) { _.next }.takeWhile{ _ != null }.toSeq
}.toSeq
```

You can also extend `Iterable` by defining your own `next` and `hasNext` method in order to use these standard methods more easily.  You might even define an implicit or explicit conversion from these Java types to this new `Iterable` type – this is the same pattern you see in `JavaConversions` and `JavaConverters`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Upon closer inspection, these java classes are actually linked lists.  does that change your implementation at all?

Comment: If you have a `java.util.LinkedList`, you should definitely look into using the helpers in `scala.collection.JavaConversions` and `scala.collection.JavaConverters`, which are designed for this exact situation.  For example, if you import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._`, you can call `myLinkedList.asScala` to get a `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer`, which unlocks all the power of the Scala collections library.

Comment: hey @Ben Riech, unfortunately, they're not `java.util.LinkedList`s, they are custom java classes that satisfy the linked list contract.  thanks for your input.